# Collectionview with multiple different collection viewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm building a survey app and I want to use such view [image: (the view)]

in this example there's only two answer possible but I want to be possible to have like 3 / 4 answer and different kind of survey,

I will receive a JSON to build it with the type of the question and the answer possible etc ..

My main problem is that I don't really know how to proceed, I'm a newbie on iOS development atm and I don't want to try too many thing and have spaghetti code so if someone have an idea on how to do this collection view with different view depending on the json

Thanks o/

Comment: You should post the code to show what you tried.

Comment: PageViewController with Presenting ViewControllers Will help I think

Comment: does your problem still exists?

Comment: Yes, I just can't figure out how to load a custom view inside the collection view and load the one I need depending on my JSON

Comment: have you tried my solution which i have posted down below?@ValentinScheldeman

Comment: yes but It was not exactly the problem I had since I know how to use a collectionView, I just switched to a UIScrollView instead

Comment: So as you wrote " on how to do this collection view with different view depending on the json" .Like UITableView, UICollectionView is a UIScrollView subclass that manages a collection of ordered items. Items are managed by a data source, which provides a representative cell view at a particular index path. so anything you want to achieve with UIScrollView can be done these as well @ValentinScheldeman

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of ways to achieve it but as in your case you want with **Collectionview with multiple different collection viewcell**

In ViewController.swift, conform few UICollectionView protocol.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

        @IBOutlet weak var mainCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
             mainCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
```

**then implement collection view data source and delegate methods.**

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}


// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    print("indexPath.row \(indexPath.row)")
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)
        if let button = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton{
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MoveToNextCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return cell
    }

    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
        if let button = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton{
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MoveToNextCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        return cell
    }

    else{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath)
        if let button = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as? UIButton{
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MoveToNextCell), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return cell
    }
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

**then implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods.**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height)


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
```

**Then finally for moving between cells**

```
func MoveToNextCell(){

        let collectionBounds = self.mainCollectionView.bounds
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionBounds.size.width))
        self.moveToCell(contentOffset: contentOffset)
    }

    func moveToPreviousCell(){
        let collectionBounds = self.mainCollectionView.bounds
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset.x - collectionBounds.size.width))
        self.moveToCell(contentOffset: contentOffset)
    }

    func moveToCell(contentOffset: CGFloat){
        let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.mainCollectionView.contentOffset.y ,width : self.mainCollectionView.frame.width,height : self.mainCollectionView.frame.height)
        self.mainCollectionView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
    }
```

That's pretty much all you need to achieve that.

Comment: does my answer help? have you tried this solution? if it does mark as answered and close the problem.